# How to recalculate (and not just scale/transform) SVG Path to fit bounding box?

Tags: svg, vega, vega-lite

I am trying to plot an [Isotype Bar Chart with Vega-Lite](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/examples/isotype_bar_chart.html). Vega-Lite supports custom SVG path strings (e.g. `"M10 10 H 90 V 90 H 10 L 10 10"`) as shapes, but it recommends the Path drawing commands to be centered within a bounding box of -1 to 1 for the x and y axis ([Vega-Lite spec](https://vega.github.io/vega-lite/docs/point.html#properties))

I have some icons that I want to use, but they don't fit in the bounding box. I tried resizing them with Inkscape, but it just adds a transformation attribute to the existing path. Of course this works for viewing the SVG in the browser (or somewhere else), but since the Path itself remains unchanged, the Vega-Lite chart displays the SVG too large and off-center.

Is there a way to actually recalculate the SVG Paths?

For the above example the solution I want would be `"M-1 -1 H 1 V 1 H -1 L -1 -1"`

Comment: In Inkscape (0.92), open the Settings popup (Shift+Ctrl+P), choose Behavior -> Transforms, select **Store transformation**: Optimized and try again to scale the path.

Comment: Thank you for the tip, but optimized is already the default selection and did not work (probably related to my specific icon). But that gave me the hint for the right google search terms (see answer below)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is about the use of graphics tools (here, Inkscape), not about programming.  Alternatively, you can include a minimal, complete, and verifiable example of your icons' code, before and after transforming them as you describe with Inkscape.

Comment: If your icons have no shapes other than paths, then depending on their nature it may be trivial to transform them programmatically: extract the path strings, pass them to a software library that parses the path, transform the path, generate the transformed path string, and reinsert the path string into the SVG.

Comment: No, this is not meant as a question about Inkscape or any other graphic tool. After the comments and my own answer I see how my phrasing could have indicated I was looking for an Inkscape answer, but this was not the case. Re: trivial: It is trivial if I would know *which* software library to use and *how* to transform the path. But this is essentially my question. I'll add the "solution path" for the path in  my question, tho.

Answer (score 1):

There is an inkscape add-on that provides the functionality of applying the transform recursively to shapes. It is convieniently named [applytransforms](https://github.com/Klowner/inkscape-applytransforms) and after installation available in the menu under `Extensions | Modify Path | Apply Transform`

Note that this will modify the path and for the example path straight lines become straight bezier curves:

`"M-1.0 -1.0C-1.0 -1.0 1.0 -1.0 1.0 -1.0C1.0 -1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0 1.0C1.0 1.0 -1.0 1.0 -1.0 1.0C-1.0 1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0 -1.0"`